# Encrypt or hide static variable in java class from decompilation

Tags: java, encryption, compilation

I need to deliver a jar file that must contains static variable values (i.e. SQL statement or password).
I am afraid from decompiling this jar file and view these variables.

How can I hide these variable values from being decompiled even from the application consumer?

Comment: You can obscure them with various methods so it's harder for a user to read them, but the bottom line is: If your program can read, then the user can read them too.

Comment: You should never put them on the client side.

Comment: By not putting them there.

Comment: You can encrypt them on client side but the user will enter a password to decrypt them.